# Adding feature to elementary os

Tags: development, elementary-project

I am new in open source projects development and maintenance 
is there any guide to start adding features or editing ones 
in elementary os ?

Answer (score 3):

I would start here:

https://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started

You can find the elementary source on Launchpad and GitHub.

Also you might look into joining the elementarycommunity on Slack.